# How do you set the payer's country in PayPal Adaptive Payments?

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using PayPal Adaptive Payments with their "embedded flow".

When sending the Pay request, I'm passing the payer's IP address in the clientDetails.ipAddress field, as well as the X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS header. 
Additionally I send the payer's country in the SetPaymentOptions request under the institutionCustomer.countryCode field (although I'm not sure what is the purpose of the institutionCustomer).

And yet, when the payer is asked to enter his address PayPal always displays United States as the default country.

Does anyone know how to make PayPal display the correct country by default?

Answer (score 3):

Finally got the solution from a PayPal developer.

When redirecting the user to the embedded flow, add a country.x parameter to the URL, for example:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=........&country.x=FR

Allegedly you can also pass a locale.x parameter, e.g. locale.x=he_IL

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,you can also use something like this:
https://www.paypal.com/**country_code**/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-47T233XXXXXXB